# rpy2 import is not working

Tags: python, pandas, rpy2

I get an error when I try to import rpy2. Here is the code and error.

```
>>> import pandas.rpy.common
Traceback (most recent call last):  

File "C:\PF\WinPython-64bit-3.3.3.3\python-3.3.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2828, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

File "<ipython-input-148-c258a0f70d44>", line 1, in <module>
import pandas.rpy.common

File "C:\PF\WinPython-64bit-3.3.3.3\python-3.3.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\pandas\rpy\common.py", line 14, in <module>
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr

ImportError: No module named 'rpy2'
```

What could be the issue? I'm using python version 3.3.3 and pandas version 0.13.1

**EDIT**

Tried to install rpy2 separately.

1. Directly using `python setup.py install` gave me an error that `os` doesn't have a module `popen3`.
2. Directly installing the exe (rpy2-2.3.9.win32-py3.3.exe) from Christoph Gohlke's site http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ run fine. But if I try to do `import pandas.rpy.common as com` then I get the following error (issue with the loading the DLL at `from rpy2.rinterface._rinterface import *` :

   ```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "C:\PF\WinPython-64bit-3.3.3.3\python-3.3.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2828, in run_code
   exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

     File "<ipython-input-10-63ebebefea80>", line 1, in <module>
   import pandas.rpy.common as com

     File "C:\PF\WinPython-64bit-3.3.3.3\python-3.3.3.amd64\lib\site-    packages\pandas\rpy\common.py", line 14, in <module>

   from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr

     File "C:\PF\WinPython-64bit-3.3.3.3\python-3.3.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\__init__.py", line 15, in <module>

       import rpy2.rinterface as rinterface
     File "C:\PF\WinPython-64bit-3.3.3.3\python-3.3.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\rpy2\rinterface\__init__.py", line 103, in <module>

       from rpy2.rinterface._rinterface import *
   ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
   ```

**EDIT**

Solved it finally. It seems like adding R_HOME and R_USER environment variables did the trick.

Comment: For version info (e.g. the need for R version 3.2), see also http://askubuntu.com/a/681142/6130

Answer (score 6):

RPy2 is a separate project from Pandas (homepage [here](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2.html)), so you'll have to install it separately. You should be able to do `pip install rpy2`, then restart Python and try again.

Answer (score 5):

This might not apply directly to your question, but ever since pandas and rpy2 have upgraded, their interface has changed. In order to set it up, you must now:

```
from rpy2.robjects import r, pandas2ri

pandas2ri.activate()
```

Now, in order to change a Pandas dataframe into an R dataframe, one must use `pandas2ri.py2ri()`, or use `pandas2ri.ri2py()` if you want change an R dataframe into a Pandas dataframe. Further information can be found at https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/r_interface.html.

Comment: Solved my problem! I think that is the correct answer atm. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Well, first you have to install rpy2. If you are using conda you can do it using the following command

```
conda install -c r rpy2
```

Then, if you want to use R on Jupyter Notebook environment you can activate R using

```
%load_ext rpy2.ipython
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case it worked when I installed it in Anaconda Prompt with a command:

`conda install -m rpy2`

After that I had to move **rpy2** directory from rpy2-2.9.0-py3.6-win32.egg (folder that was installed to) cause it didn't recognized it after installation...and moved only **rpy2** folder to the following path:

C:\Users..\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages
(where all packages are called from)

That solved problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a pandas *interface* to rpy2. Separately, you also need rpy2 installed on your system. I don't have rpy2, so it was easy for me to check this:

```
In [1]: import pandas.rpy.common
(...)
ImportError: No module named rpy2.robjects.packages


In [2]: import rpy2
(...)
ImportError: No module named rpy2
```

I installed it using pip:

```
$ pip install rpy2

In [1]: import pandas.rpy.common
```

It works! It `import rpy2` works for you, but `import pandas.rpy.common` does *not* then the problem might be more subtle.

Comment: I tried that way too. It gave me error that rpy2 needs Python 2.7 or something similar. Thereafter, I checked the rpy2 documentation and it mentions this here: http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.3/html/overview.html#background. I think the larger issue is that I am using Python 3.3 and rpy2 doesn't probably work with Python 3 or above.

Comment: @Igautier, I manually unzipped the rpy2-2.3.1 tar file and then did python setup.py install. The installation gave me an error after running fine for a few steps: "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'popen3'

Answer (score 0):

In my case it initially did not wor installing it with conda. I solved it by first changing the active environment.

```
source activate [environment Name]
conda install -c r rpy2=2.8.5
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into a similar issue. I was trying to install rpy2 using anaconda version of python(*3.6.3*). 
Below, mentioned command worked for me,

```
* python3 -m conda install rpy2
```

Answer (score 0):

I installed using, conda install -m rpy2

and moved the directory of rpy2 from rpy2-2.9.1-py3.6-win-amd64.egg folder to the path from where the packages are called during the import and then it worked.